# Summing permutation function values over the entire domain

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations

I am trying to prove the following intuitive, helpful result rigorously:

> Let $S$ be a finite set and $f: S \rightarrow S$ bijective. Let $(Y, +)$ be an Abelian group and $g: S \rightarrow Y$. Then $$ \sum_{x \in S} g(f(x))=\sum_{x \in S} g(x). $$

I was trying induction on the size of $S$ but that got me nowhere.

Comment: How do you define $\sum_{x \in S}$?

Comment: @PaulFrost I didn't think that there is much of a choice, but please clarify if I am wrong. As $S$ is finite, its cardinality is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, one can write $S=\left\{x_1{,}\ x_2{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_N\right\}$ and e.g. $\sum_{x\in S}^{ }x=\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$.

Comment: @mathslover, to clarify the question of Paul Frost: How do you sum the elements in e.g. the set $S=\{\mathbb N, 1, \alpha\}$?

Comment: @Desperado Thanks, I didn't think about that. Well, would that be fixed if I said that $(Y, +)$ is e.g. an Abelian group and thus the summation has the usual properties of addition?

Comment: You definitely need an addition on $Y$, thus $Y$ should have the structure of an abelian group. You should add this information to your question. And what is the source of your question? I can't imagine that it does not contain a definition of $\sum_{x \in S} g(x)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I added the info to my post. I formulated this question myself so that's the reason for bad formulation. I am applying this when proving properties of the determinant, which involves summing over all permutations. In this case, $S$ would be the symmetric group, $f$ some bijective operator which takes a permutation and returns another permutation, and $g$ something that takes a permutation and evaluates to something in real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function  $y : S \to Y$, we first of all need a reasonable definition of
$$\sum_{x \in S} y(x) . \tag{1}$$
This is not trivial because in $Y$ we initially we only have sums $y+y'$ of two elements.

Let us remark that we can identify functions $y : S \to Y$ with "tuples" $(y_x)_{x \in S}$ with entries $y_x \in Y$ indexed by the elements of $S$; simply take $y_x = y(x)$. This leads to writing $(1)$ in the perhaps more customary form
$$\sum_{x \in S} y_x .\tag{2}$$

The first step is to consider $S = [n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and to define
$$\sum_{i \in [n]} y(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n y(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i . \tag{3}$$
As usual the RHS is defined recursively (i.e. using induction) via
$\sum_{i=1}^0 y(i) = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} y(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n y(i) + y(n+1)$ for $n \ge 0$. Note that we allow $n=0$ in which case $[n] = \emptyset$. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^0 y(i)$ is "the sum with $0$ summands".

For an arbitrary $S$ we can choose a bijection $b : [n] \to S$ for some $n$ and define
$$\sum_{x \in S} y(x) = \sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } b} y(x) := \sum_{i =1}^n yb(i) . \tag{4}$$
Here $yb$ denotes the function $y \circ b$.
But wait, is this well-defined? Could it be that different bijections $b, b' : [n] \to S$ yield different values $\sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } b} y(x)$ and $\sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } b'} y(x)$?

To exclude this it suffices to prove that for any bijection $\pi : [n] \to [n]$ (i.e. for any permutation of $[n]$) we get
$$\sum_{i =1}^n y(i) = \sum_{i =1}^n y\pi(i) . \tag{5}$$

In fact, if  $b, b' : [n] \to S$ are bijections, then $\pi = b^{-1}b'$ is a permutation of $[n]$ and by $(4)$ applied for $yb$ we get
$$\sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } b} y(x) = \sum_{i =1}^n yb(i) = \sum_{i =1}^n yb\pi(i) = \sum_{i =1}^n yb'(i) = \sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } b'} y(x) .$$

Once we know that the RHS of $(4)$ does not depend on the choice of $b$, it is also clear that for each bijection $f : S \to S$ we have
$$\sum_{x \in S} y(x) = \sum_{x \in S} yf(x) . \tag{6}$$
In fact, take a bijection $b : [n] \to S$. Then also $f^{-1} b :[n] \to S$ is a bijection and we get

$$\sum_{x \in S} yf(x) = \sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } f^{-1} b} yf(x) = \sum_{i =1}^n yff^{-1}b(i) =  \sum_{i =1}^n yb(i) = \sum_{x \in S \textit{ via } b} y(x) = \sum_{x \in S} y(x) .$$

We shall now prove $(5)$. It is well-known that each permutation of $[n]$ can be expressed as a product of *adjacent transpositions*. These are the bijections $\tau^n_k : [n] \to [n]$ for $k = 1,\ldots,n-1$ which permute $k$ and $k+1$ and leave all other elements fixed. Thus it suffices to prove
$$\sum_{i =1}^n y(i) = \sum_{i =1}^n y\tau^n_k(i) . \tag{7} $$
$(5)$ follows then from the formula $\sum_{i =1}^n y(i) = \sum_{i =1}^n y\tau^n_{k_1} \ldots \tau^n_{k_m} (i)$ which is proved via induction on $m$.

We prove $(7)$ by induction on $n$.

The base case $n = 1$ is trivial because there do not exist transpositions on $[1]$. Now assume that $(7)$ is satisfied for all $k = 1, \ldots, n-1$. We have to show that
$$\sum_{i =1}^{n+1} y(i) = \sum_{i =1}^{n+1} y\tau^{n+1}_k(i) $$
for all $y : [n+1] \to Y$ and all $k = 1, \ldots, n$. Let $\bar y = y \mid_{[n]}$.

For $k = n$ we get
$$\sum_{i =1}^{n+1} y\tau^{n+1}_n(i) = \sum_{i =1}^{n} y\tau^{n+1}_n(i) + y\tau^{n+1}_n(n+1) = \left(\sum_{i =1}^{n-1} y\tau^{n+1}_n(i) + y\tau^{n+1}_n(n)\right) + y\tau^{n+1}_n(n+1) \\= \left(\sum_{i =1}^{n-1} \bar y(i) + y(n+1)\right) + y(n) \\= \sum_{i =1}^{n-1} \bar y(i) + (y(n+1) + y(n))  = \sum_{i =1}^{n-1} \bar y(i) + (y(n) + y(n+1)) \\= \left(\sum_{i =1}^{n-1} \bar y(i) + y(n)\right) + y(n+1) = \left(\sum_{i =1}^{n-1} \bar y(i) + \bar y(n)\right) + y(n+1) = \sum_{i =1}^{n} \bar y(i) + y(n+1) \\= \sum_{i =1}^{n} y(i) + y(n+1) = \sum_{i =1}^{n+1} y(i) .$$

For $k < n$ we get
$$\sum_{i =1}^{n+1} y\tau^{n+1}_k(i) = \sum_{i =1}^{n} y\tau^{n+1}_k(i) + y\tau^{n+1}_k(n+1) = \sum_{i =1}^{n} \bar y\tau^{n}_k(i) + y(n+1) = \sum_{i =1}^{n} \bar y(i) + y(n+1) \\= \sum_{i =1}^{n} y(i) + y(n+1) = \sum_{i =1}^{n+1} y(i).$$

Comment: What would be an intuitive idea for understanding the definition $\sum_{x\in S} y(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y \circ b)(i)$? And since you asked for my definition for that, are there any alternative definitions used?

Comment: To define the sum $\sum_{x \in S} y(x)$ we need to index the elements of $S$ in the form $S= \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and can then interpret the sum as $\sum_{i=1}^n y(x_i)$ (which is defined recursively, using only sums of two elements at each step of the recursion). Formally this means that we have to **choose** a bijection $b : [n] \to S$. The crucial point is to show that the result does not depend on the choice of $b$. This is a consequence of associativity and commutativityof $+$.

Comment: We can even say that the fact that sums $\sum_{x \in S} y(x)$  are well-defined is equivalent to  associativity and commutativityof $+$.  I do not know alternative definitions. But since you used $\sum_{x \in S} y(x)$, I asked what your understanding is.